# Other than MacBook Pro, do all other Apple laptops use the butterfly keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro

Just wondering which MacBook is worth getting?  The new MacBook pro looks too bulky to me and I'm also not a fan of the price tag either.

While shopping, I just wanted to confirm two things which I found shocking:

Is MacBook pro the only current Apple laptop I can buy right now with the scissor key mechanism?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375678/when-was-the-butterfly-keyboard-introduced-to-the-macbook-air

Answer (score 2):

No, only the 16 inch MacBook Pro has scissor keys as of December 2019. Yes, all the rest have [previous design / butterfly keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375678/when-was-the-butterfly-keyboard-introduced-to-the-macbook-air).

You can see the major releases and dates when the manuals for each model at https://support.apple.com/manuals/macnotebooks